# Stripping out headers from CSV file loading

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a file that takes the following format.

```
TIMESTAMP=Jan 20 10:22:43 2014
TYPE=text
BEGIN-FILE
value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6
value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6
value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6
END-FILE
```

I want to load this file into Hadoop, unfortunately, all the files contain lines of meta information that I want to strip out. Is there a way in Pig (or any other method) where I can ignore all lines that do not contain comma's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Pig, you can use the `FILTER` command to remove those lines if you just want to throw them away.  You could do this multiple ways; here are a couple of possibilities:

Load entire lines into a single field, filter out the ones which can't be split on comma into 6 fields, and then split them out for use in your script:

```
a = LOAD 'file' USING PigStorage('\n') AS (line:chararray);
b = FILTER a BY SIZE(STRSPLIT(line, ',', 6)) == 6;
c = FOREACH a GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(line, ',', 6)) AS (/*put your schema here*/);
```

Load as comma-separated file, and then throw away any lines with NULL in the 6th field:

```
a = LOAD 'file' USING PigStorage(',') AS (/*put your schema here*/);
b = FILTER a BY $5 IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Nice approach, note that the second method may not be used when value6 is allowed to be cast as NULL.

Answer (score 0):

In MapReduce, have the first line of your mapper parse the line it is reading.  You can do this with custom parsing logic, or you can leverage pre-built code (in this case, a CSV library).

```
protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException {
        String line = value.toString();
        CSVParser parser = new au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVParser.CSVParser();
        try {
           parser.parseLine(line);
           // do your other stuff
        } catch (Exception e) {
               // the line was not comma delimited, do nothing
        }
}
```